# How can i understand panic plist in iPhone 4s?

Tags: xcode4.5, reset, iphone-4, panic

---

I have problem - my iPhone 4S (ECID 387220092299 SN DNPH9H44DTD1 software ver 10A523) every time reboot. It can lay shuted down for some hours and i can turn it on only by holding home and lock buttons same time. i have installed xcode 4.5 on my Mac and can read panic lists or errors log but understand nothing.

Did anyone can help me or say who should i ask?

Here is a part of one panic.plist:

```
> Incident Identifier: CF491101-A83A-4E52-A15D-8AB89AE13367  
> CrashReporter Key:   ddfe39ad60a20fdbb4338ba261bd44bb2250e06c  
> Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1  
> Date/Time:       2012-12-04 15:35:56.122 +0400  
> OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)  
> 
> panic(cpu 0 caller 0x87e8a5b0): kernel abort type 4: fault_type=0x1, fault_addr=0xc  
> r0: 0x00000000  r1: 0x00000001  r2: 0x00000000  r3: 0x00000000  
> r4: 0xcfe5be90  r5: 0xcfe5bf2c  r6: 0xcfe5bf24  r7: 0xcfe5be5c  
> r8: 0x00000000  r9: 0x00000000 r10: 0x00000000 r11: 0x00000000  
> 12: 0xcfe5be20  sp: 0xcfe5bdcc  lr: 0x87ef60e7  pc: 0x87ffb0e4  
> cpsr: 0x00000033 fsr: 0x00000005 far: 0x0000000c  
> 
> Debugger message: panic  
> OS version: 10A523  
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Wed Oct 10 23:29:31 PDT 2012; root:xnu-> > > >          > 2107.2.34~2/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8940X  
> iBoot version: iBoot-1537.4.21  
> secure boot?: YES  
> Paniclog version: 1  
> Kernel slide:     0x0000000007e00000  
> Kernel text base: 0x87e01000  
> Epoch Time:        sec       usec  
>>   Boot    : 0x50bd4204 0x00000000  
>>   Sleep   : 0x50bd4bbd 0x0006bbbd  
>>   Wake    : 0x50bd4bc0 0x00000009  
>>   Calendar: 0x50bd4bc0 0x00001be3  
>> 
> Task 0x801d1c20: 12390 pages, 121 threads: pid 0: kernel_task  
> Task 0x801d1968: 272 pages, 3 threads: pid 1: launchd  
> Task 0x801d13f8: 898 pages, 10 threads: pid 13: UserEventAgent  
> Task 0x801d0e88: 623 pages, 5 threads: pid 14: wifid  
> Task 0x801d0918: 393 pages, 3 threads: pid 17: timed  
> Task 0x801d0660: 204 pages, 7 threads: pid 18: syslogd  
> Task 0x801d00f0: 272 pages, 2 threads: pid 20: powerd  
> Task 0x801ce878: 465 pages, 3 threads: pid 29: lockdownd  
> Task 0x801ce308: 327 pages, 2 threads: pid 31: installd  
> Task 0x801cdd98: 368 pages, 2 threads: pid 33: deleted  
> Task 0x801cd2b8: 1457 pages, 17 threads: pid 37: mediaserverd  
> Task 0x80748c20: 441 pages, 4 threads: pid 39: mDNSResponder  
> Task 0x807486b0: 1781 pages, 12 threads: pid 41: locationd  
> Task 0x80748140: 785 pages, 5 threads: pid 43: imagent  
> Task 0x80747e88: 331 pages, 3 threads: pid 44: iaptransportd  
> Task 0x80747918: 283 pages, 20 threads: pid 46: fseventsd  
> Task 0x80747660: 874 pages, 1 threads: pid 47: fairplayd.N94  
> Task 0x807470f0: 283 pages, 3 threads: pid 49: AppleIDAuthAgent  
> Task 0x80746e38: 685 pages, 10 threads: pid 50: configd  
>>>     thread 0x808a30a0  
>>>>>       kernel backtrace: cfe5bb20  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87e87491  fp: 0xcfe5bb50  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87e87d2d  fp: 0xcfe5bb7c  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87e17fc7  fp: 0xcfe5bb9c  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87e8a5b0  fp: 0xcfe5bc64  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87e847a4  fp: 0xcfe5be5c  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87fe31f3  fp: 0xcfe5be88  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87fe3365  fp: 0xcfe5bef8  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87fe0d85  fp: 0xcfe5bf74  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x8801ca48  fp: 0xcfe5bfa8  
>>>>>>        lr: 0x87e84340  f
```

This is only one log file. Maybe there is nothing about reason why my device make me nervous.
I can show other. Help me please.